# GCP Anthos - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add my cluster in AWS to GCP/Anthos. I follow the GCP documentation (https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/multi-cloud/aws/quickstart) but my cluster within GCP has an error with the status  "Unreachable Agent - please check if GKE Connect Agent is deployed correctly." My Antos is on and all required services are enabled. I am not sure what is missing. Are you able to help?
When I run "cloud container aws cluster create ..." from the GCP shell I noticed the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "gkemulticloud.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.gkemulticloud.v1.AwsClusters.GetAwsCluster"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed a node-pool correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable agent error is due to when Connect Gateway is not set up properly.Follow this doc and set the connect gateway.
https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/gateway/setup.
Try logging in from GCP console under GKE via the user connect gateway is setup.

Comment: The link might provide steps to help solve the problem. However, the question does not have enough information to answer it, so the link should be a comment on the question asking for more information. Links break, change, and/or are deleted. Provide the relevant details in your answer so that the link is not required.

Comment: What do you mean - try logging in from GKE console?